# How to remove div class using keyup function?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to ask you about keyup event listener, mine is not working.
when i press the key, it adds pressed class to the div. but when i release the key it won't remove the class

```js
function keyPressed(e){
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  key.classList.add('pressed');
}
function removePressed(e) {
  if(e.propertyName !== 'opacity') return;
  this.classList.remove('pressed');
}
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('keyup', removePressed))
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed);
```

```css
.pressed {
  transform: scale(1.0);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div data-key="55" class="key item6">
  <kbd>7</kbd>        
</div>
```

Comment: Define "not working". You need to explain what your code is supposed to do, what it does do and any error messages that appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

HTML:

```
<div data-key="55" class="key-item6">
      <kbd>7</kbd>        
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.key-item6').keyup(function () {
    if ($.trim($('.key-item6').val()).length) {         
        $(this).removeClass('pressed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but you can do some simple debugging. Change the following line of code:

```
  this.classList.remove('pressed');
```

To this:

```
  console.log(this.classList)
```

Here's how it should look:

```
function keyPressed(e){
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  key.classList.add('pressed');
}
function removePressed(e) {
  if(e.propertyName !== 'opacity') return;
  console.log(this.classList)
}
const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('keyup', removePressed))
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressed);
```

If the console displays your element with the class you want to remove, you're on the right track!

Comment: the console said the opacity is not defined (there is no pressed class in the div). But i already add pressed class using keydown event Listener

Comment: If opacity isn't defined, then that's why your function isn't working. Try inspecting the class after clicking on it. Does your class show up? If not, you know for sure that your keydown function isn't working.